# $addToSet used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
[
  {
    $match: {
      $and: [
        {
          $or: [
            { assignee: 'eaa68f83-5024-4a8e-93f0-4b849d598585' },
            { parent: 'eaa68f83-5024-4a8e-93f0-4b849d598585' },
          ],
        },
        { $and: [{ stage: 'COMPLETE' }] },
      ],
    },
  },
  { $group: { _id: null, valueSet: { $addToSet: '$_id' } } },
  { $project: { key: null, value: { $size: '$valueSet' } } },
]
```

I get below error as the count of records ($_id) is huge.

$addToSet used too much memory and cannot spill to disk. Memory limit: 104857600 bytes

Is there any solution for this?

Comment: is this part of an aggregation? If so, please provide complete aggregagtion and sample of docs. If not, simply do a count on your collection, as this piece of code do that.

Comment: @matthPen updated the snippet. There is a match stage before group

Comment: can you provide some docs sample?

Comment: @matthPen here is the sample - https://mongoplayground.net/p/DjgEBXEDxrg 
The issue is the number of documents is 4M+, hence the $addToSet operation fails.

Comment: Try adding `{ "allowDiskUse" : true }`

Comment: That did not help! I already have { "allowDiskUse" : true } as part of aggregation. I think its a limitation with $addToSet operation - not sure!

Comment: allowDiskUse pertains to sorting, not $addToSet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memory is limited to 100MB by default for any single $push or $addToSet operation in an aggregation pipeline.

These limits were added in MongoDB 3.6.17, 4.0.14 and 4.2.3 along with options to change the default.  See https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-44869.

**Edit**

After thinking about this for a moment, I realized the the end result is `value` will be the count of unique `_id` values of the documents in the pipeline.  This can be obtained in a more scalable way by not using $addToSet.

Instead of grouping by `null` and adding each `_id` to a set, group by `_id` and count the number of documents in the result.

```
  { $group: { _id: '$_id' } },
  { $count: 'value' },
  {
    $project: {
      key: null,
      value: 1,
    },
  },
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!  Is there a way we can set internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes in mongdb version 3.6.9 ? The admin command `db.adminCommand({setParameter: 1, internalQueryMaxAddToSetBytes: newLimit})` is not supported in 3.6.9.

Comment: Are you sure you're on 3.6.9? the memory limit error message you note in the title was not introduced until 3.6.17

Comment: I double checked it on shards and it was 3.6.19 and I was able to change the config and it worked. Thanks @Joe

Comment: But when mongo shards got rebooted, the settings got reverted nack to 100MB. How do we set this permanent ?

Comment: Set the parameter in the config file.